# Outlook office 365 mail SMTP email authentication doesn't work in django?

Tags: django, authentication, outlook, smtp, office365

[image]django settings config

```
 EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
 EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.office365.com'
 EMAIL_PORT = 587
 EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@outlook.com'
 EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'myPassword'
 EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
 EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

it shows error smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [BM1P287CA0013.INDP287.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]')